# XPATH in Android

Tags: android

I have an xml file

XMLParsing.java read all the file XML

My goal is displayed only the part when the text is equal. This code display all the file

if i try this code, it doesn't work

```
    XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    String expression = "/postes/poste";
    InputSource inputSource = new InputSource("postes.txt");
    Node nodes =(Node) xpath.evaluate(expression, inputSource, XPathConstants.NODE);
```

the error message is on this line `Node nodes =(Node) xpath.evaluate(expression, inputSource, XPathConstants.NODE)`; `inputSource can not be resolved`

and if i try this code

```
   XPathFactory xPathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
            // To get an instance of the XPathFactory object itself.
            XPath xPath = xPathFactory.newXPath();
            // Create an instance of XPath from the factory class.
            String expression = "/postes/poste[gouvernorat=text]";
            XPathExpression xPathExpression = xPath.compile(expression);

            // Compile the expression to get a XPathExpression object.
            Object result = xPathExpression.evaluate(R.raw.postes);
            //Evaluate the expression against the XML Document to get the result.
```

The error is in to lines `xPath.compile(expression);` and `xPathExpression.evaluate(R.raw.postes);`

i added this `import javax.xml.xpath.*;`

but it doesn't work

I Try DOM Parser but it doesn't work also ; i can't read the file

please help me

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is you are not targeting you application to API Level 8 (2.2) or higher. You can see on the [Xpath Documentation Pages](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html) that it is only available since API Level 8 (top right corner). Also shown by this [bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=515).

If you'd still like to support lower versions of Android, you must include a third party library to provide XPath functionality such as [dom4j](http://www.dom4j.org/dom4j-1.6.1/).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend checking XmlPullParser as long as your xml follows some sort of an easy to follow pattern - if I understood your goal correctly from your code snippet that is. It won't fix your problems with opening an inputstream from a file though but is rather handy in many cases.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your xPath expression is not well formed as:

```
    String expression = "/postes/poste[gouvernorat=text]";
```

it should be

```
     String expression = "/postes/poste[@gouvernorat='text']";
```